# UIVibrancyEffect dimmed on device, vibrant in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm experiencing poor rendering of vibrancy effect on my iPhone 6.

This is how it looks:
[image: simulator vs. device]

I've checked the value of [`UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled) and it returns false on both device and in the simulator.

The code for the background image, the effects and a containerView that I add every other elements to looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class BackgroundImageView : UIView {
    let bgImage = UIImageView(forAutoLayout: ())
    var blurView:UIVisualEffectView!
    var vibrancyView:UIVisualEffectView!

    var containerView: UIView? = nil {
        willSet(container) {
            vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(container!)
        }
    }

    init(imageName: String) {
        super.init()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        bgImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        // Scale relative to the size of the iPhone 6 Plus: http://martinnormark.com/smooth-transition-from-launch-image-to-view-controller-in-ios/
        bgImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(screenSize.width / 414, screenSize.height / 736)

        self.addSubview(bgImage)

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
        self.blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        self.blurView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.addSubview(blurView)

        let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
        vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
        vibrancyView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        blurView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()

        bgImage.autoCenterInSuperview()
        containerView?.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)
        blurView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)
        vibrancyView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perhaps that `UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled()` returns true for your iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus, so it appears darker.

To disable it, go to Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast -> Darken Colours, toggle it off should work.

**Edit**

As stated in the document [UIVibrancyEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html).

> The vibrancy effect is color dependent. Any subviews that you add to
>   the contentView must implement the tintColorDidChange method and
>   update themselves accordingly. UIImageView objects with images that
>   have a rendering mode of UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate as well as
>   UILabel objects will update automatically.

We should use images with a rendering mode of `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` to make `UIImageView` objects update automatically. Applying this makes the `UIVibrancyEffect` vibrant on iPhone device.

Comment: Nope, that was not the case either.

Comment: Can you share the image you used as background? like the image with "Host"?

Comment: Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/52u7vajsrgp6qf3/AAAJP6uepRF9DUV3lyJxuZLaa?dl=0

Just to be clear. I'm keeping the question open to allow someone to grab the bounty in the remaining 3 days. I resolved the issue, so unless you're hunting the bounty don't go over and about for it.

Comment: Sorry, I can reproduce it with the image. The image is indeed dimmed. I was using labels, so I didn't see it.

Comment: UIImageView objects with images that have a rendering mode of UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate as well as UILabel objects will update automatically. So is it possible that we should use image with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` mode? anyway, after I set it like this, they look much more similar to each other.

Comment: Exactly. That paragraph in the docs is a pot of gold. Update your answer with that description, and I'll award you the correct answer and the bounty!

Comment: Yes, docs are really important, answers can be found there. Thanks for awarding the bounty to a community member even though you have already know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I Used `var` instead of `let` in below lines and it was working for me.

```
var vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
```

May be this will help you.

I was using like this.

```
var vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
var vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
vibrancyEffectView.frame = view.bounds
```

Comment: `let` will merely mark it as a constant. Using `var` won't change the rendering. I've discovered what caused the issue, but will leave the bounty open until it expires for anyone to grab with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use generic RGB, not sRGB or device RGB.